# Arduino 33 Nano BLE Sense not compatible with pulseIn()?

Tags: ble, pulsein, arduino-nano-ble

### Preface

Currently, I'm making an application on a Arduino 33 Nano BLE Sense. I'm trying to measure the current humidity and send it via BLE to another device. The target is to send a precise value with a high frequency, 8-10 values every second.

For measuring the humidity I connected an external sensor, the [P14 Rapid Capacitive Humidity Sensor](https://www.ist-ag.com/sites/default/files/DHP14-Rapid_E.pdf) (it's faster and more accurate than the onboard humidity sensor) with a [NE555 Timer IC in Monostable Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Monostable).

To read the output pulse (frequency: ca. 500Hz) I'm using [`pulseIn()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/).

I managed to calculate the humidity correctly and also the BLE data transfer worked.

---

### Problem

My (minified) sketch:

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

void setup() {
    // some setup, takes around 10s
}

void loop() {
    BLE.poll(); // polling for new events, takes ca. 10 µs

    value = pulseIn(6, HIGH); // read the high pulse, takes around 500-4000 µs

    // calculating the average value, takes < 1 µs

    if (/* this if is executed every 1 second for testing purposes, targeted is every 100ms*/) {
        // humidity is calculated, takes ca. 20 µs

        characteristic.writeValue(/* calculated value */); // takes ca. 50 µs
    }
}
```

When I merged the features, the problems began. I couldn't connect to the Arduino anymore.

When I try to connect to it (with nrf Connect App), this happens. When I manage to connect to it before it stops working, I will be disconnected with a `GATT_CONN_TIMEOUT` exception.

[image: nrf Connect App Screenshot]

When the Arduino is powered on, the setup is called and it's connectable while the setup is running. When `pulseIn()` is called for the first time the BLE connection stops working. But the programm keeps on running.

I already tried calling `pulseIn()` only every 10s or only once, the BLE connection stops working.

And yes, commenting out the `pulseIn()` makes BLE work again.

---

### Possible Solution

Next thing I would try is to delete the `pulseIn()` and use *interrupts* for measuring the time.

**My question is if there is a better way to fix this issue?**

Comment: Likely you can not mix these two libraries.  If you are so inclined I would dive into the source code for each library in an attempt to find the conflict.  You are probably looking for both libraries using the same resource such as a timer.  Setting up your own timer as stated in the question may be easier.  It may be a bit extreme, but if you understand the underlying (to an Arduino sketch) C++ language, you might also consider destroying & constructing the BLE library ever time you want to use it.

Comment: how do you know that it stops at `pulseIn()`? ... the code that you posted has no debug functions

Comment: @jsotola as said in the question the code i posted is very *minified*. I print the value I get from the ´pulseIn()` and when it's printed the connection stops.

Comment: so it does not stop at pulseIn() ... it stops a couple of program lines after

Comment: @jsotola sorry, I wasn't very clear about *what* stops. The programm keeps running normally and I see the prints the continue. But the BLE connection stops, as seen in screenshot the device stops "existing".